# I'm trying to send a token to the header

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have send token in the header for authorization in laravel

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);
```

but the middleware is not extracting the token and returning:

> no token found

```
$token = $request->header('Authorization') ? explode(" ", $request->header('Authorization'))[1] :  null;
```

I created another middleware for data communication which actually got the token and passed it to another middleware but that's the wrong approach.

Comment: Can you share what your Kernel.php looks like for `$middleware` array?

Comment: Are you making a request _from_ your own system, _to_ your own system here?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting `bearerToken` is the right way rather than checking then explode to retrieve as there is a method in Laravel which get token from Authorization header and if no such header is present, it'll return empty string.

```
$token = $request->bearerToken();
```

> Another way to check desired header is present is to use `hasHeader()`

```
if ($request->hasHeader('X-Header-Name')) {
    //
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#request-headers